# PHP/XPath/SimpleXML: Select all attributes at once

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have the following XML

```
$data = "<data>
  <element name='A'>value1</element>
  <element name='B'>value2</element>
  <element name='C'>value3</element>
  <element name='D'>value4</element>
  <element name='E'>value5</element>
</data>";
```

It's loaded as SimpleXML object in PHP.

Using the following line of code I can get all values as an array

```
$values = array_map( create_function( '$value', 'return (string) $value;' ), $data->xpath("data/element") );
```

`print_r($values)` gives

```
Array (
  [0] => value1
  [1] => value2
  [2] => value3
  [3] => value4
  [4] => value5
)
```

Is it possible to use the same method with a different xpath query to return values of all name attributes, without looping through array created with `$data->xpath("data/element")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this XPath expression:

```
data/element/@name
```